# Dificuldade com AJAX e JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, jsonp

Estou com um problema no retorno do ajax com jsonp, ele retorna o json, mas não consigo trabalhar com ele.

**Codigo:**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://minasul.tecnologia.ws/previsao/index.php?tipo=TODAS",  
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        //QUANDO USO O SUCCESS, ELE NÃO ENTRA AQUI NESSE BLOCO
        //QUANDO USO O COMPLETLE, ELE ENTRA, MAS NÃO CONSIGO TRABALHAR COM O JSON
    }
});
```

#### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4g6mcj45/)

Comment: blz.. coloquei!

Comment: O que aontece se você deixar o `dataType: 'json'` e remover o `contentType`?

Comment: então... ele da erro de cros domain.... vc viu que ele retorna o json blzinha?

Comment: Bom galera... resolvi o problema ultilizando este link http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/

Answer (score 0):

Na sua pagina onde é executado o select vc deve dar um echo jsonencode.Exemplo:

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM TABELA';
echo json_encode($query->result());
```

Logo poderá pegar o resultado em seu ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://minasul.tecnologia.ws/previsao/index.php?tipo=TODAS",  
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: então.. vou colocar meu código php aqui:

function download_page($path){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
 $retValue = curl_exec($ch);    
 curl_close($ch);
 return $retValue;
}

Comment: $cidades = array(1162, 1288, 1354, 1567, 1871, 3318, 3637, 5442, 5599);
        $unidades = array();
        foreach ($cidades as $cod => $value){
            $url = "http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/cidade/".$value."/previsao.xml";
            $unidades[] = new SimpleXMLElement(download_page($url));
        }
        echo json_encode($unidades);

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, talvez sua dificuldade seja similar ao que eu estava tendo.
Ao invés de utilizar `$.ajax` utilize  `$.getJSON`.

Por algum motivo mesmo eu incluindo no Header as propriedades `(Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")` e `("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST")` ainda sim está com erro.

Tente da seguinte forma:

```js
 $.getJSON('Endereco_do_endpoint', function (data) {
 
      //Percorrer pelos itens retornados
      $.each(data, function (key, item) {
        console.log(item.ID);
      });
 });
```